# Sharing data between node.js app and lua app

Tags: node.js, lua, node-webkit

I have two applications, a node.js app running on node-webkit, and a lua application. I would need to pass data between the two applications on regulars intervals, say every 5 to 15 seconds.

The node.js application is the one creating the data, and the lua application is the one consuming the data. The data only goes to one direction.

How should I do the data transfer. I would prefer json/xml for the data, but actually it can be in any other format as well. The data moved at a time is not large. Its just some ten parameters at a time.

My initial thought was to just make the node app act as server and serve the data via rest api, and the lua app just read the page with LuaSocket or such. But is there a better way to do the transfer, if both of the apps reside on same machine? Currently the lua app is running in Windows, but that could change.

My background is in web development, so I'm totally lost when it comes to sharing data between applications. I'm also new to lua. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish such task. I will describe two of them.

The first approach which I like most is using a Remote Queue such as Apache Kafka, Redis, RabbitMQ, or even Zookeeper for small data, alternatively store in a database. All these remote storage systems have very good Node.js modules and all of them can handle JSON and any other data type very well.

Unless this is just a mere test app, it is good to build such fault tolerance into your apps. In your case, imagine if the consumer Lua app goes down, or the opposite, Node.js producer app goes down. You don't want the failure on one app to affect another app. In production environment, it is best to isolate apps and tasks like this. Another advantage of this approach is that one day you may decide to rewrite your consumer in Node.js, Scala, etc. or have multiple consumers in different languages. This doesn't require your server to stop or change. It even doesn't have to know about any changes to the consumer.

So, your production server always pushes data to a remote data store/queue independently, and a consumer server reads then deletes the data from this remote store on its own pace.

If you used a database, you would read the new records, consume them, and once done, remove them from the database. This approach allows you to shutdown the consumer and producer apps independently for any reason like upgrade.

Another approach is to establish a direct network connection from producer server to a consumer server via a TCP. The producer server would be a client pushing data to the consumer server. This can be accomplished with the `net` build-in module if the apps are on different physical machines. But as you can see, this is less reliable solution because if the consumer goes down, the produce can no longer push the new data in which case you should think what you should do with it: discard or store somewhere. If store somewhere, you end up reimplementing the first approach explained above.